# jQuery multiple if statements based on a variable value simplify?

Tags: jquery, banner, simplify

I've built a changing banner for some magazine issues, it's all working exactly as I want but I'm wondering if there's a better option than all the if statements I'm using to check 'issueTotal', this seems like back practise but it's currently the only way I can think of to get it to work.

Any responses would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

jQuery

```
 var issueTotal = 0;



$(document).ready(function(){

$('#backIssue0').show();

$('.prevButton').hide();    

$('.nextButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    issueTotal = issueTotal + 1;

    if(issueTotal > 0){
        $('.prevButton').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal < 4){
        $('.nextButton').show();
    }    
    if(issueTotal > 3){
        $('.nextButton').hide();
    }

    if(issueTotal == 0){
        $('#backIssue0').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal == 1){
        $('#backIssue0').hide();
        $('#backIssue1').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal == 2){
        $('#backIssue1').hide();
        $('#backIssue2').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal == 3){
        $('#backIssue2').hide();
        $('#backIssue3').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal == 4){
        $('#backIssue3').hide();
        $('#backIssue4').show();
    }

});


$('.prevButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    issueTotal = issueTotal - 1;

    if(issueTotal > 1){
        $('.prevButton').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal < 1){
        $('.prevButton').hide();
    }
    if(issueTotal < 4){
        $('.nextButton').show();
    }    
    if(issueTotal > 3){
        $('.nextButton').hide();
    }

    if(issueTotal == 0){
        $('#backIssue0').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal == 1){
        $('#backIssue0').hide();
        $('#backIssue1').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal == 2){
        $('#backIssue1').hide();
        $('#backIssue2').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal == 3){
        $('#backIssue2').hide();
        $('#backIssue3').show();
    }
    if(issueTotal == 4){
        $('#backIssue3').hide();
        $('#backIssue4').show();
    }
});

 });
```

I've built a js fiddle for the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/huddds/5Z39B/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace

```
if(issueTotal == 0){
    $('#backIssue0').show();
}
if(issueTotal == 1){
    $('#backIssue0').hide();
    $('#backIssue1').show();
}
if(issueTotal == 2){
    $('#backIssue1').hide();
    $('#backIssue2').show();
}
if(issueTotal == 3){
    $('#backIssue2').hide();
    $('#backIssue3').show();
}
if(issueTotal == 4){
    $('#backIssue3').hide();
    $('#backIssue4').show();
}
```

with this:

```
$("#backIssue" + issueTotal).show();
if(issueTotal > 0) {
    $('#backIssue' + (issueTotal - 1)).hide();
}
```

Try similarly for others.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I was trying something along those lines but couldn't get it to work so resorted to is statements. Perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `issue` class attribute to every issue element, then on prev-next click do something like this:

```
$('.issue').hide();
$('#backIssue' + issueTotal).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

This section:

```
if(issueTotal < 4){
    $('.nextButton').show();
}    
if(issueTotal > 3){
    $('.nextButton').hide();
}
```

is a bit awkward. Only one of those conditions can be true (it can't be less than four AND greater than three if you're working with integers), so you shouldn't be using two if statements; a single `if-else` statement would achieve the same result and be more readable. You could instead do this:

```
$('.nextButton').toggle(issueTotal <= 3);
```

That will show all of the matching elements if `issueTotal` is less than or equal to 3 (same as `< 4` but, for me at least, makes more sense), otherwise it will hide them.

Comment: Love the toggle. Updated my suggestion to use it

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion. **NOTE** this is the complete code

I hide the prevbutton default and added class="issue" to the divs and use this generic code

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/TfCcN/)

```
var issueTotal = $(".issue").size(); // or hardcode 5 if you must
var currentIssue=0;

$('#backIssue'+currentIssue).show(); // show initial cover

$('.nextButton, .prevButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#backIssue'+currentIssue).hide(); // hide current cover 
    currentIssue+=(this.className=="prevButton"?-1:1); // back or forward?

    $('.prevButton').toggle(currentIssue > 0); // show previous or not
    $('.nextButton').toggle(currentIssue <  issueTotal-1); // show next or not

    $('#backIssue'+currentIssue).show(); // show current issue
});
```